# Table not showing values from MySQL - servlets and jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I'm new at this, kind of learning new things everyday about jsp, servlets and so on, I have setup all to show all my users from my database into a table in the browser, and then just a button that will change just 1 value of that, so I managed to do this.

My `AdminPanel.jsp` (where I set up my table in order to show all the entries from the database)

```
  <form action="AdminPanel" method="get">

  <table style="width:100%">
      <caption>Usuarios Registrados</caption>

      <tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
    <th>Usuario</th>
    <th>Estado</th>
    <th>Habilitar</th>
  </tr>

   <tr>

    <c:forEach var="row" items="${memberList}">

    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${row.firstname}"/> </td>
        <td><c:out value="${row.lastname}"></c:out> </td>
        <td><c:out value="${row.username}"></c:out> </td>
        <td><c:out value="${row.type}"></c:out> </td>
        <td><a href="AdminPanel.jsp" name="Edit">Habilitar usuario</a> </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
  </tr>

</table>
        </form>
```

Now, I have a `userDAO` that connects to the database and setup the values for the userBean (my pojo class with all the setters and getters for firstname, lastname and so on)

**UserDAO.java**

```
  public static UserBean adminPanel(UserBean bean) {

         //preparing some objects for connection 
         Statement stmt = null;    

         String firstname = bean.getFirstName();
         String lastname = bean.getLastName();
         String username = bean.getUsername();
         int tipo = bean.getType();

            String searchQuery =
               "select firstname,lastname,username,tipo from idusuario";

      // Tracing the process
      System.out.println("Nombre:  " + firstname);          
      System.out.println("Apellido: " + lastname);  
      System.out.println("Usuario: "+username);
      System.out.println("Estado Usuario :" + tipo);  
      System.out.println("Query Panel Admin :" + searchQuery);  

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error al cargar el driver");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

      try 
      {
         //connect to DB 
         currentCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usuarios", "root", "admin");
         stmt=currentCon.createStatement();
         rs = stmt.executeQuery(searchQuery);   
         boolean more = rs.next();

         // if user does not exist set the isValid variable to false
         if (!more) 
         {
            System.out.println("Para poder utilizar el sistema debe registrarse");
            bean.setValid(false);
         } 

      } 

      catch (Exception ex) 
      {
         System.out.println("Error logueandose, posible problema de conexion de base de datos " + ex);
      } 
   } 

}
```

And my `AdminPanel.java` servlet

```
 @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {



         ArrayList<UserBean> member= new ArrayList<UserBean>();
        try {
            while(rs.next()) {
                UserBean user = new UserBean();
                user = UserDAO.adminPanel(user);
                user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
                user.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
                user.setUserName(rs.getString("username"));
                user.setType(rs.getInt("type"));
                member.add(user);
                request.setAttribute("memberList", member);
            }       } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AdminPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }
```

The results i want to retrieve in my database (with the query `SELECT firstname,lastname,username,tipo,admin  from idusuario` )

[image]

Now, in my output it doesn't show anything, the query is right I have checked it out with mysqlworkbench and it displays the results that I want, I have retrieved the data and stored it, but I don't know why is not showing anything at the moment.

This is my output

[image]

My rs is pulled out from userDAO as well , in my import

```
import static com.login.UserDAO.rs;  (resultSet)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to separate your database logic from the servlet, it makes it much easier to manage. It's also useful to create a seperate class for your database connection. The reason why you are not getting any results is because in your UserDao class you are not getting any results from the ResultSet.

Create a class for your database connection. We can call on this anytime we want to access the database.

```
public class DBConnection {
    private static String url = null;
    private static Connection conn = null;
     public static Connection getConnection(){
     try{

       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usuarios";

     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","admin");
     }   catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } 
     return conn;
     }
}
```

and our adminPanel method from the UserDao class:

```
    //Now we can use this like this, i looked at your code and saw you wanted to have a list of UserBean objects.. we can do that like this:
public List<UserBean> adminPanel(){
    ArrayList<UserBean> users = new ArrayList<UserBean>();
    //get connection from our DBConneciton class we created earlier
    try(Connection conn= DBConnection.getConnection()){
    //create our sql statement
   PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("select firstname,lastname,username,tipo from idusuario;"); 
         //execute query
         pst.executeQuery();   
       //now get results
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
      //while ResultSet has results
     while (rs.next()) {
    //create new user object to hold the info in
    UserBean user = new UserBean();
    //get the results from resultset     
    String firstname = rs.getString(1);
    String lastname = rs.getString(2);
    String username = rs.getString(3);
    int type = rs.getInt(4);
    //set results to user object
    user.setFirstName(firstname);
    user.setLastName(lastname);
    user.setUserName(username);
    user.setType(type);

    users.add(user); //add userobject to list of userobjects

      }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     //we don't need to close our db connection because the try statement does it for us   
return users; //return list of users
}
```

Now to access this all we need to do in our servlet is this:

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

          UserDAO u = new UserDAO(); //instantiate class

       //get our list of users
     List<UserBean> users = u.adminPanel();
       //set our list to request
     request.setAttribute("memberList", users);

     //forward to jsp page
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("AdminPanel.jsp");
            rs.forward(request, response);


    }
```

everything on your jsp looks fine so should work, let me know if you have any questions or problems

**EDIT:** some debugging ideas:

In your servlet do this to see how big your users list is:

```
...
//get our list of users
List<UserBean> users = u.adminPanel();
 //check if we are actually getting something from the database
 System.out.println(users.size());
```

If size is 0 then that means there is something wrong with our query. Check to see if you are getting anything from your database if you manually query your database with the following query:

```
select firstname,lastname,username,tipo from idusuario;
```

**EDIT 2**

Try removing the `<c:out tags:`

```
  <c:forEach var="row" items="${memberList}">
    <tr>
        <td>${row.firstname}</td>
        <td>${row.lastname}</td>
        <td>${row.username}</td>
        <td>${row.type}</td>
        <td><a href="AdminPanel.jsp" name="Edit">Habilitar usuario</a> </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the time and help

Comment: no problem, feel free to mark this as the correct answer if it helped solve your problem :)

Comment: i have one problem, i implemented the code but it seems its not showing anything

Comment: i think the problem might be with your query, check my edited answer. Let me know what happens with that debugging

Comment: oh, i got this from the syso USUARIOScom.login.UserBean@4107eeb0

Comment: its bringing out 4 of those, so its retrieving good each item in the db

Comment: nope, in the chrome debugging i see blank like the image of the question, the log just brings me this error repeated 4 times

Comment: so when you visit the url for the servlet, it doesn't bring you to the jsp page?

Comment: it brings the page but not the results

Comment: its like the output in my question

Comment: okay if you are getting 4 results from your database, then our problem is in the front end. It must have something to do with your jsp, check my edited answer and try that, let me know what happens

Comment: im saying that im getting 4 results with this error  USUARIOScom.login.UserBean@4107eeb0  , four of the same type, im not getting any results from the database

Comment: yeah that's fine, it's not an error, it's a reference to the element inside the object. You are getting 4 of those because there are 4 users in your table. Try the edit i made to my answer

Comment: ok, now at (users.size()); im getting 4, but the results are not showing in the UI of the page, still blank, but i think we are getting closer

Comment: above the log that shows 4 , its still saying USUARIOScom.login.UserBean@44485d0   i think the error keeps in the jsp

Comment: That is because somewhere in your code you are doing another `System.out.print();` on your UserBean object, it's not an error. Did you try removing the `<c:out` from your jsp? Check my edited answer

Comment: yep i removed it and still the same, what a weird thing

Comment: are you sure all the code you are doing is exactly the same as mine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171590/discussion-between-jonathan-laliberte-and-gaston-saillen).

Comment: This guy is the best of the best, thanks so so so much, talented and with a lot of skills !